# select n-th li inside div

Tags: javascript, html

I have this html

```
<div class="dotstyle">
<ul>
    <li class="current"><a href="javascript:void(0)"></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"></a></li>
</ul>
```

How can I select n-th `li` element? sometimes I need second, sometimes third etc.

I'm selecting `dotstyle` class using that: `document.getElementsByClassName('dotstyle')[0]` but how can I go till li?

Comment: This might help : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `querySelector()` with `:nth-child()` pseudo-class. [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/rv193dno/1/)

```
document.querySelector('.dotstyle li:nth-child(3)').style.background = 'red'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```js
 var lItems = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].getElementsByTagName("li");
    lItems[2].innerHTML = "<p>hello</p>";
```

```html
 <ul>
        <li class="current"><a href="javascript:void(0)"></a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"></a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"></a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"></a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"></a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"></a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"></a></li>
    </ul>
```

if you want to jQuery then

```js
$( "ul li:nth-child(2)" ).append( "hello li" );
    $( "li" ).eq( 3 ).css( "background-color", "red" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
        <li class="current"><a href="javascript:void(0)"></a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"></a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"></a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"></a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"></a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"></a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"></a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var myListItems = document.getElementsByClassName('dotstyle').getElementsByTagName('li');

for (i = 0; i < myListItems.length; ++i) {
   // logic for doing something with the elements 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery has a list of selector which makes easier to select element using id,class or attribute.

You can select the child of an element using jquery in just one line.

```
$( ".dotstyle ul li:nth-child(2)" )
```

This gives the 2nd child which of type li.

[:nth-child() Selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)